# Pandas - equivalent of str.contains() in pandas query

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Creating a dataframe using subsetting with below conditions

```
subset_df = df_eq.loc[(df_eq['place'].str.contains('Chile')) & (df_eq['mag'] > 7.5),['time','latitude','longitude','mag','place']]
```

Want to replicate the above subset using query() in Pandas.However not sure how to replicate str.contains() equivalent in Pandas query. "like" in query doesn't seem to work

```
query_df = df_eq[['time','latitude','longitude','mag','place']].query('place like \'%Chile\' and mag > 7.5')

place like '%Chile'and mag >7.5 
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I'm grasping at straws here, but you _might_ be able to use python's `in` operator if you set the `engine='python'`.  If it works, it will likely end up with a pretty inefficient query (normally `pandas` tries to use `numexpr` to speed things up but `numexpr` doesn't support the `in` operator ...)

Comment: AFAIK, SQL `like` operator is not yet implemented in pandas `query()` method, so you can't do it using `query()` method

Comment: Thanks for your comments.Yeah like operator isn't there so the work around remains str.contains()

Comment: Hi from Chile, I'm wondering why you use `.iloc` in this case the following should be enough `df_eq[(df_eq['place'].str.contains('Chile')) & (df_eq['mag'] > 7.5)][['time','latitude','longitude','mag','place']]`

Answer (score 12):

As of now I am able to do this by using the `engine='python'` argument of the `.query` method to use `str.contains` inside a query.

This should work:

```
query_df = df_eq[['time', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'mag', 'place']].query(
    "place.str.contains('Chile') and mag > 7.5", engine="python")
```

Answer (score 9):

What I think is going on here is that you are not able to utilize the method `str.contains` within the `query` pandas method. What you *can* do is create a mask and refer to that mask from within `query` using the at sign (@). Try this:

```
my_mask = df_eq["feature"].str.contains('my_word')
df_eq.query("@my_mask")
```

Comment: Useful for code-complete in my_mask command but not inside string for query in my jupyter-lab.

Answer (score 8):

Using str.contains works for me in pandas 1.0.0 with this syntax:

```py
df.query("columnA == 'foo' and columnB.str.contains('bar')")
```

Comment: Check if "numexpr" module is installed or not. If not, a default "python" engine is used where `str.contains` is a valid expression.