# how to use re inside the query method of pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is a follow up question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38662011/6347629)

What is the best way to include the re flags inside the query.

The following way throws an error

```
condition = f"(col1.str.contains('{val}', flags={re}.IGNORECASE)"
df.query(condition)
```

Syntax Error:

```
....
File "<unknown>", line 1

 col1.str.contains ('val',flags =<module 're'from '/xxxx/lib/python3.7/re.py'>.IGNORECASE )

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you could instead use the corresponding inline flags:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':list('aaAAbC')})

condition = f"col1.str.contains('(?i)a')" 
print (df.query(condition, engine = 'python'))
```

Note that `(?i)` is the inline flag that corresponds to re.IGNORECASE. I tend to believe that `re.DEBUG` is the only flag that does not contain a corresponding inline flag. check [python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for the corresponding inline flags

Answer (score 1):

For me working pass variable with `@` and add `engine="python"`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':list('aaAAbC')})

a = re.IGNORECASE
condition = f"col1.str.contains('a', flags=@a)"

print (df.query(condition, engine="python"))
  col1
0    a
1    a
2    A
3    A
```