# Querying a dataframe to return data where a column contains specific letters

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe `df` which looks like the below:

[image]

I can query the dataframe using pandas `.query` to return specific rows as below:

```
df.query('Data == "05h"')
```

Is it possible to amend the above to return rows without hard coding the `0` before `5h`, so it essentially returns all rows which contains `5h` in the string?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - equivalent of str.contains() in pandas query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662011/pandas-equivalent-of-str-contains-in-pandas-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for the substring you want as follows

```
df2 = df[df['Data'].str.contains('5h')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my proposition

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-02-01', '2023-02-01', '2023-02-01'],
                   'data': ['05h', '05f', '05h', '05f']})

df = df.loc[(df['data'].str.contains('5h'))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it this way:

```
df.loc[df.Data.str.contains('5h')]
```

Also, you could get the same result as your query using:

```
df.loc[df.Data == '05h']
```

this way you don't have to hardcode your column name.